# my site takes ages to load without www. prefix

Tags: web, dns, server, nameservers

gpstudios.com hangs for about 5 - 10 seconds
www.gpstudios.com loads instantly.

I've got it so it redirects to www.gpstudios.com if its missing for URL consistency.

What's going on? Must be something wrong with the DNS setup, but it succeeds all DNS checks with external DNS testing services (eg - http://www.dnsinspect.com/gpstudios.com)

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you have two A records registered for gpstudios.com - the first server is needing to timeout before the second record is retrieved. This is simple round robin fallback, and entirely expected. Delete the second IP and it should work as expected.

```
gpstudios.com.      14399   IN  A   8.33.137.137
gpstudios.com.      14399   IN  A   198.245.51.152

www.gpstudios.com.      14399   IN  A   198.245.51.152
```

Comment: Bingo! I got in to a right tizzy when I was setting up DNS, didn't notice that was still there.
Thanks!! :)